# npm install fails with "npm ERR! Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined" when using my own Blueprint

Tags: jhipster

I have created my own Blueprint, and I am trying to use it with a local version of JHipster (following the rules here: https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/).

However when running npm install I get:

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/my_project/node_modules/.staging/minimist-19b0b9f9/package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/my_project/node_modules/.staging/p-limit-6a9bed74/license'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/my_project/node_modules/.staging/minimist-19b0b9f9/LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/my_project/node_modules/.staging/p-limit-6a9bed74/index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/my_project/node_modules/.staging/minimist-19b0b9f9/index.js'
```

(this goes on for over 100 lines)

logging ends with:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: yeoman-test@2.2.0 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-test):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: yeoman-assert@3.1.1 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-assert):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sinon@7.2.5 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/sinon):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: mocha@6.1.4 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/mocha):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: jsdoc@3.6.3 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/jsdoc):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: eslint-plugin-prettier@3.1.0 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: eslint-plugin-import@2.18.2 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: eslint-config-prettier@6.1.0 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/eslint-config-prettier):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.0.0 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: eslint@6.2.2 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/eslint):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ejs-lint@0.3.0 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/ejs-lint):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: chai@4.2.0 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/chai):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli@1.0.10-4.2.3 (node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2020-03-11T04_43_33_553Z-debug.log
```

In that log I see:

```
38893 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined
38893 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/action/extract.js:67:20
38893 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
38893 verbose stack     at Function.Promise.fromNode.Promise.fromCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:185:30)
38893 verbose stack     at extract (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/action/extract.js:63:13)
38893 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/actions.js:75:20
38893 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
38893 verbose stack     at Function.Promise.fromNode.Promise.fromCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:185:30)
38893 verbose stack     at runAction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/actions.js:74:13)
38893 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/actions.js:54:16
38893 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
38893 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
38893 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
38893 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:611:10)
38893 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:142:12)
38893 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
38893 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
```

Versions used:

- node: v12.16.1
- npm:  v6.13.4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with node >=  12.16.1. I couldn't find a solution so instead made a change locally and continued. Not sure if the same option is ok for you. The failure is at extract.js file (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/action/extract.js). In the extract method, by adding a `spec!==undefined` check before assigned spec.raw or spec.type, the issue failure can be bypassed. `args[0] = spec !== undefined ? spec.raw : ''` and `if (ENABLE_WORKERS && spec !== undefined && (isRegistry(spec) || spec.type === 'remote')) {`